# How do I pass in options to React Google Map?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I'm trying to make my google map require Ctrl (Command on mac) + scroll to zoom in and out instead of just scroll. In the documentation, it says I need to change gestureHandling to coopertive, but I'm having trouble passing it in to map options.

I've tried:

```
  <Map options={{ gestureHandling: 'coopertive' }}
       style={style}
       google={props.google}
       zoom={2}>

    {listMarkers}
  </Map>
```

and I've also tried:

```
  <Map
       style={style}
       google={props.google}
       zoom={2}
       gestureHandling= 'coopertive'>

    {listMarkers}
  </Map>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this question without knowing which Google Maps implementation you did, was it directly from Google Maps API or from a third part React Component?

---

Anyway, supposing that you implemented the Google Maps API directly, the `gestureHandling` option from Google Maps API can be set in two ways:

1) As option when creating a new instance of `google.maps.Map`:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8,
          gestureHandling: 'cooperative'
        });
```

Documentation: [Google Maps gestureHandling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction#gestureHandling)

2) Or as a parameter from `google.maps.MapOptions` method:

```
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8,
        });

map.setOptions({ gestureHandling: 'cooperative' });
```

Documentation: [Google Maps Map Options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.gestureHandling)

Comment: Ah thank you. I didn't realize I was using a third party package.